# How to implement several independent devices on one FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga

I need implement 2 or more independent device on FPGA (Altera Cyclone III). For example: two counters by one and by two. How I do this make? And how to use this devices parallel? Thanks everybody!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everything happens in parallel on an FPGA. Heres an example solution in verilog

**Counter Module**

```
module counter #(
    parameter pCntNum =1
    ) (
    input iClk,
    input iRst,

    output reg [7:0] oCnt
);
always @ (posedge iClk)
    if (iRst) begin
        oCnt <=0;
    end else begin
        oCnt <= oCnt +pCntNum;
    end    
endmodule
```

**Top module**

```
module top (
    input iClk,
    input iRst,

    output [7:0] oCntBy1,
    output [7:0] oCntBy2
);

    //Instantiate count by 1 module
    counter #(
        .pCntNum(1)
    )counter_by_1_inst(
        .iClk(iClk),
        .iRst(iRst),
        .oCnt(oCntBy1)
    );

    //Instantiate count by 2 module
    counter #(
        .pCntNum(2)
    )counter_by_2_inst(
        .iClk(iClk),
        .iRst(iRst),
        .oCnt(oCntBy2)
    );
endmodule
```

There are many many ways to do this, however I gave a solution which I think best exemplifies what you are asking.

EDIT: I just saw the tag for VHDL and not Verilog. The same approach and mechanisms apply to a VHDL solution,however Quartus accepts both Verilog and VHDL source files (You can even have a code base with both). With a simple VHDL tutorial you will be able to create a solution equivalent to the Verilog one I wrote if need be.